# How do I cast an Enum to its underlying type BEFORE calling instance method, in one line?

Tags: c#, lambda, enums, int, string-formatting

I ran across the need for this answer when attempting to try:

```
(int)myEnum.ToString("D2");
```

This doesn't work, because it thinks I'm trying to cast the string return value from `.ToString("D2")`

Of course it's easy enough to do:

```
var myInt = (int)myEnum;
myInt.ToString("D2");
```

BUT, I want to know if a one line solution exists so that I can use this in a lambda i.e.

```
// Assuming this worked how I wanted it to
myEnums.Select(myEnum => (int)myEnum.ToString("D2"))
```

Goal here is to transform my IEnumerable of myEnum into left zero-padded ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add another pair of parentheses:

```
var x = ((int)myEnum).ToString("D2");
```

i. e. your linq query would look like this:

```
var x = myEnums.Select(myEnum => ((int)myEnum).ToString("D2"));
```

Comment: derp, and here I was admiring my well formatted question.